# Group within a group in BigQuery Standard SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a following table:

```
| item | day_of_purchase |
|------|-----------------|
| A    | 1               |
| B    | 2               |
| C    | 3               |
| A    | 1               |
| C    | 1               |
```

I want to count how many of each item we have for each day. I cant use GROUP BY day_of_purchase since it would group A and C in this case. So I need to somehow group items by day_of_purchase but only within their own type.

Result table would look like this:

```
| item | day_of_purchase | count |
|------|-----------------|-------|
| A    | 1               | 2     |
| B    | 2               | 1     |
| C    | 1               | 1     |
| C    | 3               | 1     |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP BY` accepts multiple columns; just separate them with commas. For example:

```
select item, day_of_purchase, count(*)
from t
group by item, day_of_purchase
```

See [Google Cloud - Standard SQL Query Syntax](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax).

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using

```
<window_function>
  OVER (
      [PARTITION BY <expr>]
      [ORDER BY <expr> [ASC | DESC]]
      [<window-frame-clause>]
     )
```

where `<window function>` is `COUNT(*)` in this case

```
SELECT DISTINCT item, day_of_purchase,
       COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY item, day_of_purchase ) AS "count"
  FROM tab;
```

without using `GROUP BY` clause.